# Allowing app installs from “unknown sources” for Secondary Users on Android 4.4.2

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, multi-user, unknown-sources

I see that "Unknown Sources" under `Settings → Security` on Android 4.4.2 is greyed out (I can't enable it) for my Secondary user on my Nexus 7, Is it expected behavior? Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: The Secondary user is not with a restricted profile

Answer (score 2):

Android by default does not allow secondary users (Restricted Profiles) to install apps from `Unknown Sources`.

But, under `Application and Content restriction` for the particular user, you can enable specific menu in `Settings` menu. You can check whether `Unknown Sources` can be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just click it 10 times in a row and then it will ask you are you sure then just click yes and then there you go your ready

Comment: Or 20? Or, 30? This question concerns secondary users. How confident is that answer, since I don't believe secondary users have any control over this?

Comment: Please supply some source for this statement of "fact"?

Answer (score -2):

Enable it from the *Owner user* then it is enabled for all secondary users

Comment: This is clearly not the case, as implied by the OP's own statement. Obviously they already enabled it from the owner's user profile, and that didn't resolve the issue. Also, this was already answered an entire year ago, and correctly.