# Enable "Unknown sources" for secondary user

Tags: multi-user, unknown-sources

How do I enable unknown sources on secondary user because she I try install the file it says enable unknown sources but when I go on settings the unknown sources is greyed sand it's disable and I can't enable it.please help me

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60799/allowing-app-installs-from-unknown-sources-for-secondary-users-on-android-4-4 and https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149994/enableing-unknown-sources-installation-from-2nd-user-on-android-6-0